# Typescript with ReactJs and MobX getting error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

all

I am getting error while running command like npm start and also installed all packages using npm install but not working.

I am sharing my screenshot:[image]

Comment: Please include error messages in your question as text, not images.

Comment: "message": "It's not clear which file to import for '@import \"initial-variabl
es\"'.\nCandidates:\n  initial-variables.sass\n  initial-variables.css\nPlease d
elete or rename all but one of these files.\n",

Comment: seems rather webpack related not react, mobx or typescript.

Comment: Post the log file listed - the 2018-04-05T12_27_43_096Z-debug.log - that might help us give you some direction. Also post the source file that is failing if its a file you wrote.